# webview for google maps v3 shows blank screen

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm following the tutorial to implement google maps v3 for a project which displays the simple map and after figuring out the mostRecentLocation null pointer error it now displays the map and centres on my location.

I figure that I should really be loading an html file from my assets folder which contains the javascript and api link for the google maps api and that this will allow the use of the built in zoom buttons?  When I do this the webview displays an empty screen.  Should I be setting the webview to load the html?  If so can anyone tell me why I might have a blank screen?

I have api v1 and 2 working but would prefer to use v3 if I can.

```
private void setupWebView(){
    final String centerURL = "javascript:centerAt(" +  mostRecentLocation.getLatitude() + "," +  mostRecentLocation.getLongitude()+ ")";  
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();  
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.getJavaScriptEnabled();
    settings.getBuiltInZoomControls();
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    //Wait for the page to load then send the location information  
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());  
    //webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.html");
    webView.loadUrl(MAP_URL);
    /** Allows JavaScript calls to access application resources **/  
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "android");
    }
```

and the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript"   src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
var map;  function initialize() {    
var latitude = 0;    
var longitude = 0;    
if (window.android){      
    latitude = window.android.getLatitude();      
    longitude = window.android.getLongitude();    
    }    
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);    
var myOptions = {      
        zoom: 20,      
        center: myLatLng,      
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  

        }    
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),      myOptions);  }  
function centerAt(latitude, longitude){    
    myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);    
    map.panTo(myLatLng);
    }
</script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `<div id="map_canvas"></div>` in your body, so google knows where to place the map (that's the element you have in your JS for a new map).  The div also needs a size.

Adding this worked

```
<body>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 100px; width=100px;"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">initialize();</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi  I have tried this with height and height set to 100% entered in css file and then the html but am still having the same result either way.

Comment: Upon closer look, you're not calling your `initialize` function. See my edited answer.  This worked for me.

Comment: I have the map displaying now. Along with the div the following code was needed.  Though I am going to edit it to what you have put to see what happens.  

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

I found a few more map examples online and looking at the page source noticed the above line and added it above the centerAt function.  Though I didn't get the zoom buttons as I expected but assume I need to look at the javascript for that.  Main thing for tonight is the map is now showing and centered where it should be with the zoom level I set.

Thank you.