# Seeing a blank page with Google maps api

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3

As per link below I'm trying to have Google maps with a user being able to click the map to specify a location but I just see a blank screen:
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3

I made some changes as per link here but it made no change:
[webview for google maps v3 shows blank screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046734/webview-for-google-maps-v3-shows-blank-screen)

Errors as follows from Google Chrome Console:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < phpsqlinfo_add.html:33
Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize is not defined phpsqlinfo_add.html:123

Appropriate lines highlighted below in code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
 Copyright 2008 Google Inc.
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0:
 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Saving User-Added Form Data Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var marker;
    var infowindow;

    function initialize() {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419);
      var options = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);
      var html = "<table>" +
                 "<tr><td>Name:</td> <td><input type='text' id='name'/> </td> </tr>" +
                 "<tr><td>Email:</td> <td><input type='text' id='email'/></td> </tr>" +
                 "<tr><td>Phone:</td> <td><input type='text' id='phone'/></td> </tr>" +
                 "<tr><td>Town:</td> <td><input type='text' id='town'/></td> </tr>" +
                 "<tr><td>County:</td> <td><select id='county'>" +
                 **<option value='Outside Ireland' SELECTED>OutsideIreland</option> +**
                 <option value='Antrim' SELECTED>Antrim</option> +
                 <option value='Armagh' SELECTED>Armagh</option> +
                 <option value='Carlow' SELECTED>Carlow</option> +
                 <option value='Cavan' SELECTED>Cavan</option> +
                 <option value='Clare' SELECTED>Clare</option> +
                 <option value='Cork' SELECTED>Cork</option> +
                 <option value='Derry' SELECTED>Derry</option> +
                 <option value='Donegal' SELECTED>Donegal</option> +
                 <option value='Down' SELECTED>Down</option> +
                 <option value='Dublin' SELECTED>Dublin</option> +
                 <option value='Fermanagh' SELECTED>Fermanagh</option> +
                 <option value='Galway' SELECTED>Galway</option> +
                 <option value='Kerry' SELECTED>Kerry</option> +
                 <option value='Kildare' SELECTED>Kildare</option> +
                 <option value='Kilkenny' SELECTED>Kilkenny</option> +
                 <option value='Laois' SELECTED>Laois</option> +
                 <option value='Leitrim' SELECTED>Leitrim</option> +
                 <option value='Limerick' SELECTED>Limerick</option> +
                 <option value='Longford' SELECTED>Longford</option> +
                 <option value='Louth' SELECTED>Louth</option> +
                 <option value='Mayo' SELECTED>Mayo</option> +
                 <option value='Meath' SELECTED>Meath</option> +
                 <option value='Monaghan' SELECTED>Monaghan</option> +
                 <option value='Offaly' SELECTED>Offaly</option> +
                 <option value='Roscommon' SELECTED>Roscommon</option> +
                 <option value='Sligo' SELECTED>Sligo</option> +
                 <option value='Tipperary' SELECTED>Tipperary</option> +
                 <option value='Tyrone' SELECTED>Tyrone</option> +
                 <option value='Waterford' SELECTED>Waterford</option> +
                 <option value='Westmeath' SELECTED>Westmeath</option> +
                 <option value='Wexford' SELECTED>Wexford</option> +
                 <option value='Wicklow' SELECTED>Wicklow</option> +
                 "</select> </td></tr>" +
                 "<tr><td>Name of Location:</td> <td><input type='text' id='location'/></td> </tr>" +
                 "<tr><td></td><td><input type='button' value='Save & Close' onclick='saveData()'/></td></tr>";

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: html
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: event.latLng,
          map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    });
    }

    function saveData() {
      var name = escape(document.getElementById("name").value);
      var address = escape(document.getElementById("address").value);
      var type = document.getElementById("type").value;
      var latlng = marker.getPosition();

      var url = "phpsqlinfo_addrow.php?name=" + name + "&address=" + address +
                "&type=" + type + "&lat=" + latlng.lat() + "&lng=" + latlng.lng();
      downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
        if (responseCode == 200 && data.length <= 1) {
          infowindow.close();
          document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Location added.";
        }
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request.responseText, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 100px; width=100px;"></div>
  **<script type="text/javascript">initialize();</script>**
</body>
  <!-- Commenting out line to edit suggestion from stackoverflow
  <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
    <div id="message"></div>
  </body> -->
</html>
```

Comment: your commented one was correct, there is no call to initialize()

Comment: @sandy Changed to commented out initialise but exactly same comments but different lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have invalid syntax starting here:

`**<option value='Outside Ireland' SELECTED>OutsideIreland</option> +**`

It looks like you are trying to concatenate all of the `options` using the javascript concatenating syntax `+`. If you go this route then you need to add double quotes around all of your `options`.

The other route is to remove all of the `+` and just use a double quote at the start of the `html var` string and the end.

Comment: Those ** are just to highlight the text in bold but I added the double quotes and I have the map showing. That worked a treat. Thank you.